Summoning knights from the other world
You play Black pieces and you just moved your pawn to b2. Now it's White to move next, but right before that, you summon 2 black knights from the other world into the game (and don't put the white king in check). Where would you put them to get a winning position for yourself?

Hints:

You should realize that you can't solve it without an engine :)

You don't have to prove the position is correct. Just show (it) along with some reasonings.

If something is part of the puzzle statement then it shouldn't be in a spoilered hint. I wrote a solution, and before posting it thought to check the hint and discovered that the hint contained an extra constraint that forbade that solution.

@GarethMcCaughan I'm pretty sure the introduction contained that constraint. Maybe it was not clear?

@QuýNhân "without white king noticing" was too vague, yeah. Current version is good

I blindly moved around the knights in an endgame tablebase until I found a position it marked as a win for black. I have no idea why it's a win for black. Is that sufficient for an answer or are you looking for analysis of why black has forced mate?

Nice puzzle! Here's a link to try it interactively.
Add two black knights, then click "Analysis Board" and click the toggle switch to see the evaluation of the position.

Looks like there's at least 4 solutions

To you all, I won't spoil too much now and I don't recommend using brute-force test, but if you found it, then it is counted as a solution, just remember having good reasonings is a part of the puzzle as well.

@TomSirgedas A full Syzygy tablebase search confirms only 4 solutions.

My solution is like this:

 

The main idea is:

 Black wants the pawn to queen.
 Black threatens either bxa1=Q+ or b1=Q+.
 b1 is guarded by Na3, so we want to kick that Na3 away, by placing black knight at Nc4, and then guard it using the second knight.
 There are multiple options, but Nd2 seems best, if not simply because it also guards b1, and itself guarded by the king. But seems like Na5 might work as well, as the main thing is to protect Nc4.

 Main play by white is only N1c2 (Nb3 is met with Nxa3 and queens next, N3c2 can be countered with Ke4).
 Black can reply Kd3, and not too deep analysis can see whatever Nc2 does after this, black can always maintain its king around c2 (to prevent white king going there) and white will run out of check for black to take Na3 with safety (no forking black king and the pawn).

The answer was helped with the engine to help see white possible play, from there I got that Na1 is white's weak point, and the rest follows from there. I confirmed with the engine about the winning position of my answer.

Congratz! You have found a correct solution.
